What kind of transform does light go through when reflected?
I believe that in an electromagnetic wave the "electro" and "magnetic" parts are orthogonal to each other. So when light hits a mirror, does the wave rotate 180 along the axis of propagation like a bullet spins or does it flip the other way? As I understand it, for the purpose of interference, if the light rotates and spins like a bullet then constructive and destructive interference will be the same for both portions. But if the wave just flips then only one part will be reversed from the other. I'm sorry if I didn't explain my question well, this is just something I'm curios about

Did you tried to check The Feynman lectures vol. II chapter 33? Here https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_33.html#Ch33-S1
